# Different Authentication Schemes for the Same ASP.NET Web API

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, authorization

### The Situation

I have an upcoming project where the web pages will be making AJAX calls. External clients will also be provided a REST API. I will be implementing this project using ASP.NET MVC 4 with Web API.

I have seen various examples online where people use the `[Authorize]` attribute for security. I presume this is whenever Web API is called via AJAX on a web page.

I have also seen various examples where an API key was passed along with each request (via query string or header). I presume this is whenever Web API is called from an external system.

### The Questions

Here are the questions that immediately come to mind:

- Should I be creating a separate controller for internal and external clients?
- or should I force the web pages to use the same external authentication model?
- or is there a way that external clients can use the Authorize attribute?
- or should I somehow support both forms or authentication at the same time?

### A Side Note

A colleague pointed out that I might want to deploy the API to a totally different URL than where the web app is hosted. Along the same lines, he pointed out that the external API may need to be more coarse grain or evolve separately.

I don't want to reinvent the wheel, here. This makes me wonder whether I should be using Web API as an internal API for my AJAX calls in the first place or if I should stick to old-school MVC actions with `[HttpPost]` attributes.

Answer (score 5):

`[Authorize]` attribute is not meant only for Ajax. When you apply the `[Authorize]` attribute to say an action method, what this does is it ensures the identity is authenticated before the action method runs,irrespective of the clients making the request and irrespective of the type of credentials submitted to your API. All it looks for is `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`. Here is the copy-paste of the code from the `Authorize` filter.

```
protected virtual bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    ...
    IPrincipal user = Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
    if (user == null || !user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        return false;
    }
    ...
}
```

As you can see, all it does it gets the `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` and checks if the identity is authenticated. Of course, when you include the roles, there are additional checks.

So, what this means is that you will be able to use different means of authentication as long as `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` is set as a result of authentication. If you have two handlers (or `HttpModules` in case of web hosting) or authentication filters in case of Web API 2, you can establish the identity based on different factors. For example, you can have a `BasicAuthnHandler` and a `ApiKeyHandler` added to `config.Handlers` and hence run in the web API pipeline one after the other. What they can do is to look for the credentials and set `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`. If `Authorize` header comes in the basic scheme, `BasicAuthnHandler` will authenticate and set `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` and if the API key comes in, it does nothing and `ApiKeyHandler` sets `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`. Both handlers can create same type of prinicipal say `GenericPrinicpal` or even different one. It does not matter because all the principals must implement `IPrincipal`. So, by the time `Authorize` filter runs, `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` will be set and authorization will work regardless of how you authenticate. Note: If you web host, you will also need to set `HttpContext.User` as well, in  addition to `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`.